# Black box impedance...how do I test?

Tags: audio, circuit-analysis, impedance

I have an audio circuit that I need to find the internal impedance of the circuit. How do I do this by only changing the output impedance of the circuit and taking measurements? I know I did this back in school but forgot how to solve. Basically, I need to find internal resistance of a black box without knowing the total voltage being supplied. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you model the black box as a voltage source in series with an impedance, then you can obtain enough data to calculate the values of these parameters by measuring the output voltage open circuit and with a resistive load at 2 different frequencies.  You will have to solve the equations for a voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

Basically with a voltage divider approach you may find the source impedance.
As you did back in school, this document will give you a good refresh to find a solution:

[INPUT and OUTPUT IMPEDANCE](https://www.pdx.edu/nanogroup/sites/www.pdx.edu.nanogroup/files/2013_Input_output_impedance_9.pdf)